# Change Input background color as entry is validated

Tags: jquery, forms, input, xmlhttprequest

I've been using this code to check the location a user enters in the input field exists in our DB.  Currently if it does match a separate span is updated to show that it matches.

However I'd like to change this so the input box the user is currently in has it's background colour updated if there is a match.

```
function location(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("location").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("location").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","check.php?loc="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

check.php queries the DB and returnes `#FFFFFF` if theres no match, and `#C000C0` if there is a match. Instead of updating the span with the ID location, I'd like to update the actual input boxes background color.

In another script I use     `$(this).css("background-color", color);`
Is it possible to use the same ? and use $(this) so it updates the field they are currently in ?

As the page is a form the location field is named loc[] and could appear multiple times, so using $(this) may make it easier to find the actual input field they are currently in.

Thanks

Comment: If the another script that you mentioned is used in the same page (implies jQuery is included on the page), then YES. You can use `$(<id of input box>).css("background-color", color);`.

Comment: @srvikram13 Thanks for the reply. I was hoping to use $(this) and not $(<id of input box>) as each input has the same name/id.  Thinking about that they should have unique ID's..  Thanks

Comment: Element IDs in an HTML page are supposed to be unique. If you wish to access a bunch of similar or related elements, consider using a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In another script I use $(this).css("background-color", color); Is it
>   possible to use the same ? and use $(this) so it updates the field
>   they are currently in ?

You can pass the `event` source object using `this` kewword, you need to add new parameter to the location function.

```
function location(str, source)
{
    $(source).css("background-color", color);

    //OR

    source.style.backgroundColor = color;         //or using native method


   ///Your code goes here.
}
```

**Edit** Based on comments

You are already passing this.value you should pass this and do not need second parameter

```
function location(source)
{
    str = source.value
    $(source).css("background-color", color);

    //OR

    source.style.backgroundColor = color;         //or using native method    

   ///Your code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand. I'll try this and see what I get.

Comment: I'm using `onkeyup="location(this.value)" ` if I try to change this.value to str it errors.

Comment: Then you do not need seocnd parameter onkeyup="location(this)" and in location function use source.value

Comment: Thanks - I keep getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: source is not defined`

Comment: did you change the function signature, you had str as parameter, function location(str) would be function location(source)

Comment: I'm calling it using: `onkeyup="location(this)"` and the function is set as `function location(source)
{
     str = source.value
`
If I alert on str I get the value I'm entering into the form, not the form id. ?

Comment: It works... if I use `    $(source).css("background-color", color);
` but not when I use source.backgroundColor = color;

Comment: My mistake here, you need source.style.backgroundColor = color; you need only one of these statements though.